# Create an observable that emits all values so far

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have an `Observable<Foo>` that emits some values but never completes.  Let’s call that `source`.  I want to create an `Observable<[Foo]>` that emits all of the items that `source` has emitted so far, whenever `source` emits.

For example, if `source` emits a then b then c, the result must emit [a] then [a, b] then [a, b, c].

How can this be accomplished?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You can use the `scan` operator, where the accumulator is an array, and the closure adds on element to it on every new event: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#Scan However this is quite strange, and would get really slow and crazy really fast, if you're not careful.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica My observable is quite short-lived, so your idea is a perfect fit for my needs.  If you create an answer I'll mark it as accepted.  Thank you!

Comment: done. Also keep in mind that the array copying will make your emitted events be `O(number_of_historical_events)` rather than the usual `O(1)` with regular event use.

Comment: That's very good to know, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scan operator, where the accumulator is an array, and the closure adds on element to it on every new event.

http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#Scan

However this is quite strange, and would really quickly become get really slow and crazy, if you're not careful.